# List all weeks,months and year in JAVA/Android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to list the all weeks/date given two date range for example:

Date from **1/1/2013** to **1/1/2020** 
 result will be:

- 1-7,2013
- 8-14,2013
- 15-21,2013 and soon til 2020 and same with month.

Comment: sure, go for it.  Let us know of any errors / problems you encounter

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea on how to do this part, still searching for a reference similar to my problem.

Comment: well weeks, months, year sounds like a calendar to me. Hmm maybe search for `java calendar` ?

Comment: Ahh okay okay, i also search similar like calendar but i have no idea upon getting the dates and range of the weeks, like 1-7,2013 and soon.

Comment: Reference: [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: So you want the first week to go from Tuesday, January 1, 2013, through Monday January 7? You don’t want to take into account on what day of week the week begins? Just asking to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this for the case of weeks(check if you can optimize).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // to provide month range dynamically

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date minDate = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5); // current month + 5 months calendar
    Date maxDate = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String startDate = dateFormat.format(minDate);
    String endDate = dateFormat.format(maxDate);

    List<Date> dates = getDates(startDate, endDate); // to get dates between range
    int prevIdentifier = 0;
    int identifier;
    String initDate, finalDate;
    List<WeekDay> weekDays = getListOfWeeksFromListOfDates(dates); 
    SimpleDateFormat dformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    SimpleDateFormat yformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    initDate = dformatter.format(weekDays.get(0).getDate());
    finalDate = dformatter.format(weekDays.get(0).getDate());
    String outputData = "";
    for (WeekDay weekDay : weekDays) {
        identifier = Integer.parseInt(weekDay.getWeekIdentifier()); // this value will be same for all days in same week
        if (prevIdentifier != 0 && identifier != prevIdentifier) {
            if (outputData.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                outputData += initDate + "-" + finalDate + "," + yformatter.format(weekDay.getDate());
            else
                outputData += "  *  " + initDate + "-" + finalDate + "," + yformatter.format(weekDay.getDate());
            initDate = dformatter.format(weekDay.getDate());
        } else {
            finalDate = dformatter.format(weekDay.getDate());
        }
        prevIdentifier = identifier;
    }
    System.out.println("OUTPUT DATA :" + outputData);

}

 public List<WeekDay> getListOfWeeksFromListOfDates(List<Date> listOfDates) {
    List<WeekDay> listOfWeeks = new ArrayList<>();
    WeekDay weekDay;
    for (Date date : listOfDates) {
        weekDay = new WeekDay(date, new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(date));
        listOfWeeks.add(weekDay);
    }
    return listOfWeeks;
}

public class WeekDay {

    Date date;
    String weekIdentifier;

    public WeekDay(Date Date, String WeekIdentifier) {
        this.date = Date;
        this.weekIdentifier = WeekIdentifier;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getWeekIdentifier() {
        return weekIdentifier;
    }

}

private static List<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2) {
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;

    try {
        date1 = df1.parse(dateString1);
        date2 = df1.parse(dateString2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);


    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    while (!cal1.after(cal2)) {
        dates.add(cal1.getTime());
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: You are using the badly designed and long outdated date and time classes (`Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateFormat`). Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). While someone might use the old-fashioned classes, please at least mention that there is an option of a better solution. One can use java.time on not new Android, you will just need [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: This was something similar I have used in previous works and I am not familiar with the new update. So I mentioned to "check if he can optimize". Thanks for your update @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I would use a `LocalDate` for start date (e.g., 1/1/2013) and one for end date (1/1/2020). To represent the period you want (week, month or year) I might use either the appropriate `ChronoUnit` constant or — more flexibly — a `Period`. The mentioned classes are from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. A pretty simple loop will iterate through your start dates (Jan 1, Jan 8, Jan 15, etc.). Subtract 1 from each start date (except the first) to get the end dates (Jan 8 minus 1 day gives Jan 7, etc.).

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- Documentation of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) and [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html).
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).